# Unable to get virtual hosts on nginx

Tags: linux, debian, webserver, nginx

I installed nginx on a raspberry pi to do some simple development work.  I have 3 files in /etc/gninx/sites-available that are also symlinked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.  They have straight forward setup at the moment.

Example.com has the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

The other 2 websites have the same setup except that the root directory and the server_name are different.

I have the /etc/hosts file updated on the local machine so that when I use the browser to example.com or any of the other 2 websites, there isn't an issue finding the website.  However, they all show the default debian nginx page.

The nginx.conf has the following:

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

     server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

#   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search for "VirtualHost *:80"  tags in nginx configuration file then my answer is that you won't find it. VirtualHost is used in apache server. In nginx it is represented by "server {  listen 80;"

Comment: I meant virtual host as an idea, not a configuration tag.  In this case I guess it is server blocks.

Comment: Sadly, while I was never able to find a fix for this, the answer ended up being that I install apache and setup virtual hosts.